# Can't build mod_wsgi on Windows 10 - "Cannot open include file: 'ws2tcpip.h'" - Have VS 2019 Build tools

Tags: python, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I have apache 2.4 installed (64 bit), python 3.7 (64 bit) (installed from Anaconda, if that matters) and VS 2019 C++ build tools, with the SDK and everything else required to build this checked. I still cannot build mod_wsgi with pip install. How can I get this to work on Windows 10?

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, python, visual studio & visual studio build tools, and apache. I have tried all the various visual studio command prompts. I have checked stack overflow, github, and other sites. There were others with similar issues but the solution of installing build tools did not work for me because a.) I already had it, b.) I reinstalled everything and it still didn't work.

`pip install mod_wsgi`

Resulting error message:

```
Collecting mod_wsgi
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/03/a3ed5abc2e66c82c40b0735c2f819c898d136879b00be4f5537126b6a4a4/mod_wsgi-4.6.7.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mod-wsgi
  Building wheel for mod-wsgi (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\VC046230\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\VC046230\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-12r9v42f\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\VC046230\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-1q_bver8' --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: C:\Users\VC046230\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi
  copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
  copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
  copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
  copying src\server\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management
  copying src\server\management\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
  copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
  copying src\server\management\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\docs
  copying docs\_build\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\docs
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\images
  copying images\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\images
  copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\images
  running build_ext
  building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\server
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\Apache24/include -IC:\Users\VC046230\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\VC046230\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" /Tcsrc/server\mod_wsgi.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi.obj
  mod_wsgi.c
  C:\Users\VC046230\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-12r9v42f\mod-wsgi\src\server\wsgi_apache.h(39): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ws2tcpip.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mod-wsgi
```

Comment: Facing the same issue. If you found out the reason, please share.

Answer (score 3):

I just solved the same problem. My config is Windows 10, Python 3.8.1, Apache2.4.39-Win64-VC15-OpenSSL1.1.1b, mod-wsgi 4.7.1.

1) I installed using [Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16:)

- Visual Studio Build Tools Main Components
- SDK for Windows 10 (10.0.18362.0) since I'm using Windows 10
- MSVC 140 - C++ VS 2015 (v.14.00)

2) Then I added C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin to `PATH`

3) Then I got the next error:

```
'apr_perms_set.h': No such file or directory'.
```

I downloaded the [file](https://github.com/traviscross/apr/blob/master/include/apr_perms_set.h) and put it into $APACHE_DIR\include

4) Then I got third error:

```
fatal error LNK1158: cannot run ‘rc.exe’.
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158
```

I took following files `rc.exe rcdll.dll` from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86 and paste them into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin

5) Congratulations!

Comment: Thank you I will have to try this and see if I can get it to work now!

Comment: God bless ya! I'm not sure if there's some issue with x86 and x64 libs and due to some inconsistencies we had to go through this hell...

Comment: i've resolved all my issues by simpy downloading and installing xampp. so if you want to save some time that would be probably the better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who had this issue, the following github issue helped me resolve it: https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/194

I had already installed Visual C++ Redistributable, so I was confused why pip install mod_wsgi still was not working.

All I ended up having to do was install Windows 10 SDK from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/

(might also need 8.1 if it still does not work)